# how to get rid of spaces between variables and strings when printed

Tags: python, string, variables

```
name = 'Alan'
print('My name is', name, '.')
```

When these two lines are run, there is a space between `'Alan'` and the period. How do I get rid of the space between them?

Comment: use trim function

Comment: Use a format string, e.g. `print(f'My name is {name}.')` or use optional arguments to the `print` function

Answer (score 8):

You can set `sep=''` but then explicitly mention the space before the name:

```
print('My name is ', name, '.', sep='')
```

A better way might be using string formatting:

```
print('My name is {}.'.format(name))
```

With python 3.6+, you can use f-strings for a more concise way of doing the same thing:

```
print(f'My name is {name}.')
```

Finally, the least flexible alternative is just concatenating the strings together:

```
print('My name is ' + name + '.')
```

You can even replicate what `print` does internally when you set `sep=''`:

```
print(''.join(['My name is ', name, '.']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
name = 'Alan'
print('My name is', name + '.')
```

or

```
name = 'Alan'
print('My name is '+ name + '.')
```

Comment: Phenomenologically correct, but `,` does not add a space

Comment: @MadPhysicist The reason I mentioned while printing. I am aware that it forms a tuple if you do it when you are not printing it.

Comment: Your reasoning is misleading even if the final result happens to match.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ok, I will remove my reasoning then.

Answer (score -1):

here comes the magic

```
name = 'Alan'
print('my name is '+name+'.')
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two good ways to accomplish this. The best way is to use the optional argument to `print`, which is `sep`:

```
print('My name is', name, '.', sep='')
```

Another way is to use [string concatenation](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python). It's a little bit slower, but you can extend the concept to a lot of other areas. Concatenating strings joins them together without a space in between:

```
print('My name is' + name + '.')
```

Comment: Both versions will drop the space before the name.